# cakephp htaccess for production install

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

So, I have cakephp installed in what I believed to be the appropriate way for production code with actual cake files above the public_html folder. The app folder is removed from the cake folder and placed at the same level.

Loading the home page works fine with the databases and the debug working.

However, in trying to run some test files I get a 404. Obviously, I need some way to direct something like www.example.com/posts/index to the proper location. I am not sure as to why this is necessary since the index.php file tells cake where the app directory is located?

Also, if I need to use the .htaccess file, how do I point to the proper location and exactly what am I pointed at?

Update - I get the errors when I follow the blog tutorial and navigate to www.mywebsite.com/posts/index

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "However, in trying to run some test files I get a 404.".  Also, there is not really a "correct" way to install CakePHP.  The current way that's considered best practice (or at least what most that I know are using), is to use composer to include CakePHP, which actually puts the CakePHP files within your app/Vendor directory.  But again, I don't think there is a "correct" way.  And you likely shouldn't have to be messing with .htaccess files.

Comment: I make the controller, model, and view in the blog tutorial, but navigating to the posts/index/ address produces a 404.

Comment: is mod_rewrite on for your server?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a production install the url `example.com` should point at `app/webroot/`, and the only .htaccess file you need is the [default one from the webroot](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.9/app/webroot/.htaccess)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Be sure to use the `.htaccess` file which corresponds to the exact version of CakePHP you are using as it has changed over the years.